# Angularjs destory/delete huge array and free memroy

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

AngularJS 1.2.28

I have 3 tabs each displaying different type of values, all objects are in the memory. I m using ng-repeat and lot of filters to iterate and display the listing as following, slicedOff is getting created on the fly is that causing memeory leak ?
I have 3 collections of large set which i am displaying. any way if i click 2nd tab free destory/delete slicedOff and free up memory ?

```
<tr ng-repeat="off in slicedOff = (filteredOffers | filter:offerViewState.filterOptions.vodFilterText | filter:{offerType:'vod', offerStatus: offerViewState.filterOptions.vodOfferStatusFilter, linearInfo: offerViewState.filterOptions.linearDetailFilter}) | orderBy:offerViewState.filterOptions.sortBy:offerViewState.filterOptions.sortByReverse | startFrom:(tableParams.currentPage-1)*tableParams.itemsPerPage | limitTo:tableParams.itemsPerPage">
</tr>
```

I noticed if i call splice and try to remove all items it is even taking more memory
help appreciated

Comment: better do those multiple filters in controller or angular will run those a lot of times. but I still thinks that's huge chunks of filters, may be rewritten with custom function that slice off those.

Comment: consider also upgrading to `1.3` or higher which introduced 1-way bindings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you getting throuble with Angular Watches. For each variable or functions, angular creates a lot of watches.

Try to use this lib https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce, it will create only one watch for your iterator. There are a lot of examples, you should try to solve this issue.

Comment: I have updated my angularjs version to 1.4.4 and bindonce is default feature you can prefix bindonece as :: to the elements